# Android: ProgressBar в AsyncTask

Tags: android, java, android-asynctask

Засунул ProgressBar в AsyncTask, но он вылетает.

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { ...
      showList();
      ...
    }

    private void showList()
    {
        TextTask task = new TextTask(getApplicationContext());
        task.execute(Utils.OpenFile(nameOfFile, this));
    }

    class TextTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
        {
            ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
            Context context;

            public TextTask(Context c)
            {
                context = c;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                mProgressDialog =
                        ProgressDialog.show
                                (context
                                        , "Loading"
                                        , "", true);

                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... text_task)
            {
               ***
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        ....
```

Ошибка:

```
Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:550)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:302)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:216)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:141)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
        at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
        at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
        at com...ShoppingList.BlistViewer$TextTask.onPreExecute(BlistViewer.java:364)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

замените

```
TextTask task = new TextTask(getApplicationContext());
```

на

```
TextTask task = new TextTask(this);
```

параметром для любого Dialog должен быть не просто контекст, а именно **Activity**

Comment: @Роман Захаров  а как во фрагменте это сделать?